# Passing Controller variable to JavaScript file in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP MVC I have retrieved some data from database. I want to pass that variable to JavaScript file.

**my controller code :**

```
 using (issue_management_systemEntities db = new issue_management_systemEntities())
        {

            var lineInfo = db.line_supervisor.Where(x => x.supervisor_emp_id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            var mapInfo = db.line_map.Where(y => y.line_id == lineInfo.line_line_id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View();
        }
```

I want to pass `mapInfo.map` variable to js file as this

```
var mapext = 'mapInfo.map'
```

how can I do that?

Comment: If you have `@model mapInfo`, you can try `var mapext = '@Model.map'` (make sure to `return View(mapInfo)` first). Or else assign to a `ViewBag` and use it like `var mapext = '@ViewBag.map'`.

Comment: Possible duplicates of [Asp.net mvc passing a C# object to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145716/asp-net-mvc-passing-a-c-sharp-object-to-javascript), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756829/pass-c-sharp-model-from-view-to-javascript & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419676/assigning-the-model-to-a-javascript-variable-in-razor.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not binding a model to the view, you could store the data in a viewbag;

```
ViewBag.mapInfo = db.line_map.Where(y => y.line_id == lineInfo.line_line_id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Then on the script part of your view file;

```
var mapext = '@ViewBag.mapInfo';
```